# Applying map function to a nested tibble in R

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, purrr

I'm trying to replicate an 'old' R script I found for the tidyverse package.

```
library(dslabs)
DataTib<-as_tibble(us_contagious_diseases)


DataTib_nested <- DataTib %>%
  group_by(disease) %>%
  nest()

Mean_count_nested <- DataTib_nested %>%
  mutate(mean_count = map(.x=DataTib_nested$data, ~mean(.x$count)))
```

As I understand, I have a tibble where data was grouped by disease and the remaining variables/data were nested, and then I'm trying to add a new column which should represent the average for variable "count" on that nested dataframe.

But I get the error, which I don't quite understand:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `mean_count`.
x Input `mean_count` can't be recycled to size 1.
i Input `mean_count` is `map(.x = DataTib_nested$data, ~mean(.x$count))`.
i Input `mean_count` must be size 1, not 7.
i The error occured in group 1: disease = "Hepatitis A".
```

Thanks in advance and best regards!

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Do you need to `nest` the data? If you just want average count for each `disease` you can do `DataTib %>% group_by(disease) %>% summarise(mean_count = mean(count, na.rm = TRUE))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is slightly wrong:

```
DataTib_nested <- DataTib %>% 
  group_by(disease) %>% 
  nest(data = - disease) 

Mean_count_nested <- DataTib_nested %>% 
  mutate(mean_count = map_dbl(data, ~mean(.x$count)))
```

Note that I use `map_dbl`
 instead of `map` since the return value is numeric.